# Firebase AB-testing iOS user targeting with app version not working

Tags: android, ios, firebase, ab-testing, firebase-remote-config

The remote config is working fine and trying to target user with version with 'exactly match' operator, the values not reflecting at the client side. The same configuration is working fine for android and without version criteria it is working for iOS also.

When using the contains operator with values 0.1.0,0.1.1 it is not working for both android and iOS.

The version giving here is showing under user properties in firebase console properly.

Firebase version using are, latest for iOS and 11.8.0 for android.

Any one faced this issue and any clue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an alternative approach of setting the version number/Build number as a User Property in my code and I create my Remote Config Conditions based on that. Hope this helps.

Here is the sample code for it.

```
func setUserPropertyForBuildNumber() {

    if let buildNumber = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleVersion" as? String {
        Analytics.setUserProperty(buildNumber, forName: "build_number")
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot from Firebase on how I use it

[image: Here is a screenshot from Firebase on how I use it]

Comment: So for you also, the normal approach is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue I had a similar issue with Firebase A/B testing & iOS.

I was able to resolve this by using the CFBundleVersion value instead of CFBundleShortVersionString value.